# Call Smarty in Javascript

Tags: javascript, smarty

I am trying to call a Smarty Code **{lang key="firstNameNotNumeric" section="account data"}** in my JavaScript File but can't get what is wrong. Adding '' did not help me too.

```
(function() {
    $('#exampleStandardForm').formValidation({
        framework : "bootstrap",
        fields : {
            standard_email : {
                validators : {
                    notEmpty : {
                        message : {
                            lang key="firstNameNotNumeric" section="account data"
                        }
                    },
                    emailAddress : {
                        message : 'The email address is not valid'
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    });
})();
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping Smarty code in single quotes (`'{lang key="firstNameNotNumeric" section="account data"}'`) ?

Comment: Yes than I get out only the Smarty Code..

Comment: When you say "my Javascript File", you mean a .js file? How exactly are you using it in the page?

Comment: I am calling the .js File inside the Smarty Template

Answer (score 0):

You have to escape your javascript with `{literal}` if it is in a smarty-template:

```
{literal}
(function() {
   $('#exampleStandardForm').formValidation({
     framework: "bootstrap",
     fields: {
       standard_email: {
         validators: {
           notEmpty: {
             message: {/literal}{lang key="firstNameNotNumeric" section="account data"}{literal} 
           },
           emailAddress: {
             message: 'The email address is not valid'
           }
         }
       }
     }
   });
 })();
 {/literal}
```

see: http://www.smarty.net/docsv2/en/language.function.literal.tpl